# How to append multicolor text in JavaFx textArea

Tags: javafx, textarea

This is actually my first JavaFx desktop application. Within my application I want to display every event as a log in textarea. I have different log types , error,warning etc. I want to append all these logs inside a textarea with different colors. I tried like this(this is just a sample),

```
 // Method call is like this
  logText("Enter Ip address First");


// The method 
public void logText(String log){
        log = ">> "+ log +"\n";
        Text t = new Text();
        t.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #DFF2BF;-fx-text-fill: #4F8A10;-fx-font-weight:bold;");
        t.setText(log);
        txtConsole.appendText(t.toString());
    }
```

With above code I did not get any error but my output is like :

```
    Text[text=">> Enter Ip address First
", x=0.0, y=0.0, alignment=LEFT, origin=BASELINE, boundsType=LOGICAL, font=Font[name=System Regular, family=System, style=Regular, size=12.0], fontSmoothingType=GRAY, fill=0x000000ff]
```

How can I solve this ? I tried various methods mentioned here in stackoverflow (this is one of them).

*** Please note that this application is for corporate use so I need to be strict to the licenses.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to have `t.getText()` in place of `t.toString` in `txtConsole.appendText(t.toString());`

Comment: You can't have colored text in TextArea. Try using [TextFlow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html) instead.

Comment: Or have a look at [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to have replace `t.toString()` with `t.getText()` in `txtConsole.appendText(t.toString())`

**You can't have colored text in TextArea**. Try using [`TextFlow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html) instead.

You have colored text which you can add to the `TextFlow`:

```
public class TextFlowSample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TextFlow flow = new TextFlow();
        String log = ">> Sample passed \n";
        Text t1 = new Text();
        t1.setStyle("-fx-fill: #4F8A10;-fx-font-weight:bold;");
        t1.setText(log);
        Text t2 = new Text();
        t2.setStyle("-fx-fill: RED;-fx-font-weight:normal;");
        t2.setText(log);
        flow.getChildren().addAll(t1, t2);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(flow), 300, 250));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

*If you have the flexibility to use external library, have a look at [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX)*

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work.  I did it as , I add a textFlow in my GUI using Scenebuilder , Then I use FXML id and addAll like u did above . See http://pastebin.com/j0MEFYpS

Comment: My fault, the css that you are using aren't valid for Text. For a complete list of css fields available for text, please go through the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide for Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text). I have edited my solution with a MCVE.

Comment: Wow, that's Perfect. It is actually working :D , wonderful. Sorry but one more question. I am still unable to make it scroll , how can I make it scroll able?