# JavaFx TextArea change color of selected text

Tags: java, string, javafx, colors, textarea

I am making a text editor with JavaFx for my own to learn.
Now I want the feature to change the color of the text that you have typed in a TextArea.
But I want it to be like Word, that you can select a specific part of your text and change that color

For example I have the sentence: "Hello my name is Bob", as a user I want to be able to select the words "is Bob" and change only that color.

Currently I have the ability to change color with the following code:

```
editorView.getInputField().setStyle("-fx-text-fill:" + picker.getChoosenColor());
```

But it changes the color of everything in the TextArea.

The object TextArea has a function `.getSelectedText()` which returns exactly the part I want to color but it returns as a String. And I can not apply `setStyle()` to a String.

So I wonder how can I achieve the functionality that I want?

Comment: JavaFX text components don’t support multiple styles for different parts of the text. There’s a third party component called [`RichTextFX`](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX) that supports this.

Comment: was a mistake . i think you could try this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149504/how-to-append-multicolor-text-in-javafx-textarea

Comment: @GiovanniContreras thx for your response, but if highlight a text in the middle line it will get hard with that method and I am not even sure if it will work.

Comment: @James_D Also thx for your response. What you recommend me seems like the solution. But a problem is that I have never used a external library and don't know really how to start with RichTextFX. Currently I try to figure out how to implement it. If you have any tutorials or documantation about it it could be really helpfull.

Comment: If you want to implement this on your own, from scratch, then I suggest using a `TextFlow` with multiple `Text` objects. Each `Text` object can be styled differently. You'll probably need a backing model to know which segments have which styles. To implement scrolling you can wrap the `TextFlow` in a `ScrollPane`. If you're not using JavaFX 9+ then implementing hit tests and text selection may be more difficult. Note you can look at how JavaFX implements `TextField` / `TextArea` and how RichTextFX is implemented to help you learn—both are open source.